# rvm problems syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: macos, ruby, rvm

Whenever I cd or use rvm commands this shows up:

```
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/initialize: line 80: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'   
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/initialize: line 80: `  fi'   
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/hook: line 32: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
-bash: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/hook: line 32: `fi'
```

This randomly started to happen. Any ideas?

Here are my paths:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
/usr/local/rvm/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/X11/bin
/opt/sm/bin
/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin
/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin
```

Update:
The problem fixed itself after I updated to OS X 10.8

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess now, but this would happen in restricted(limited) shell, like when `bash` is executed via `sh` link, or when run with `bash -r`. make sure you use login shell like `bash -l`, validate your shell in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Aren't these rvm scripts standalone, specifying the correct script interpreter? Would these particular restrictions get inherited somehow..?

Comment: rvm is sourced into the running session, so it is running in the same shell as user opens, RVM2 will have smaller wrapper for this tasks, where all code will be running in it's own shell (separate build).

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstall rvm - that fixed my issue

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```